I can't receive notification through topic with firebase
I subscribe my device token to a topic and send the message to the topic. However, the device does not receive the message sent to the topic.
ps. I have tried android and ios devices, and got the same results.
Tested Scenarios:

When sending a message to the device token, I can receive it.
Subscribed the same token to the topic, and in the response, I saw a successful binding with the number 1.
In Firebase's Cloud Messaging console, when adding a new push message based on the topic, I can see the topic I just subscribed to.
Based on the above information, it shows that the token, topic, and subscription information and behavior are all valid.

When sending a message to the topic, although the response I got is message_id, the device with the token does not receive the push message.
Is there anything I can try or troubleshoot the process?
The following is my golang code
[Initialize firebase app] - works
func NewFirebaseNotifier() (IExternal, error) {

    var app *firebase.App
    var err error

    if config.GetSystemENV().RunMode == config.RunModeLocal {

        projectID := config.GetFirebaseEnv().ProjectID

        opt := option.WithCredentialsFile(projectID)

        app, err = firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("error initializing app: " + err.Error())
        }

    } else {

        projectConfig := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: config.GetFirebaseEnv().ProjectID}
        if config.GetFirebaseEnv().ProjectID == "" {
            projectConfig = nil
        }

        app, err = firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), projectConfig)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("error initializing app: " + err.Error())
        }
    }

    if config.GetSystemENV().RunMode != config.RunModeProduction {
        fmt.Println("Firebase app initialized", app)
    }

    return &FirebaseNotifier{app: app}, nil
}

[Push token] - works
func (e *FirebaseNotifier) SendMessageToTokens(fm dto.PushMessageTokens) *dto.APIError {

    if err := checkMessage(fm.Message); err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        err,
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.RequestErr,
        }
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    fmt.Println("tokens app:", e.app)
    client, err := e.app.Messaging(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        errors.New("error getting Messaging client: " + err.Error()),
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.FirebaseClientErr,
        }
    }

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    message := &messaging.MulticastMessage{
        Notification: &messaging.Notification{
            Title:    fm.Message.Title,
            Body:     fm.Message.Body,
            ImageURL: fm.Message.ImageURL,
        },
        Android: &messaging.AndroidConfig{
            Priority: "high",
            Notification: &messaging.AndroidNotification{
                Icon:  "stock_ticker_update",
                Color: "#0000FF",
            },
        },
        Tokens: fm.Tokens,
        Data:   fm.Data,
    }

    // Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    response, err := client.SendEachForMulticast(ctx, message)
    if err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        errors.New("error sending Messaging: " + err.Error()),
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.FirebaseSendMessageErr,
        }
    }

    if config.GetSystemENV().RunMode != config.RunModeProduction {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        fmt.Println("message tokens:", fm)
        fmt.Println("Successfully sent message:", response)
    }

    return nil
}

[Subscribe to topic] - works
func (e *FirebaseNotifier) SubscribeTopic(fs dto.Subscription) *dto.APIError {

    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := e.app.Messaging(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        errors.New("error getting Messaging client: " + err.Error()),
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.FirebaseClientErr,
        }
    }

    response, err := client.SubscribeToTopic(ctx, fs.DeviceIDs, fs.Topic)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if config.GetSystemENV().RunMode != config.RunModeProduction {
        fmt.Println("subscribe success:", fs)
        if response.FailureCount > 0 {
            // List of errors in the same order as the registration tokens.
            for idx, err := range response.Errors {
                fmt.Println("Failed to subscribe to token:", fs.DeviceIDs[idx], "error:", err)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(response.SuccessCount, "tokens were subscribed successfully, tokens: ", fs.DeviceIDs)
    }

    return nil

}

[Send message to topic] - not works
func (e *FirebaseNotifier) SendMessageToTopic(fm dto.PushMessageTopic) *dto.APIError {

    if err := checkMessage(fm.Message); err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        err,
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.RequestErr,
        }
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    fmt.Println("topic app:", e.app)
    client, err := e.app.Messaging(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        errors.New("error getting Messaging client: " + err.Error()),
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.FirebaseClientErr,
        }
    }

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    message := &messaging.Message{
        Notification: &messaging.Notification{
            Title:    fm.Message.Title,
            Body:     fm.Message.Body,
            ImageURL: fm.Message.ImageURL,
        },
        Android: &messaging.AndroidConfig{
            Priority: "high",
            Notification: &messaging.AndroidNotification{
                Icon:  "stock_ticker_update",
                Color: "#f45342",
            },
        },
        Topic: fm.Topic,
        Data:  fm.Data,
    }

    // Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    response, err := client.Send(ctx, message)
    if err != nil {
        return &dto.APIError{
            Err:        errors.New("error sending Messaging: " + err.Error()),
            StatusCode: apiprotocol.FirebaseSendMessageErr,
        }
    }

    if config.GetSystemENV().RunMode != config.RunModeProduction {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        fmt.Println("message topic:", message)
        fmt.Println("Successfully sent message:", response)
    }

    return nil
}

[reference]
send message to tokens
subscribe topic
send message to topic

You should mention the device details, operating system and your code[Main issue]

Please edit your question to show the code that subscribes to the topic, and then code that sends to the topic. Also see How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Thanks for the recommendations, I have edited my question with minimal examples. I use golang and the devices I have tried are android (pixel7) and ios (iphone 11), real phones not simulators.

I suspect that your subscription process is not working even though you dont get an error.  Youre suppsoed to register the fcm token of the client device, and you are registering “deviceID” which may be different.

[Update] We discovered an interesting phenomenon. Currently, we are assigning permissions to the service account (SA) via GKE. If the SA provided to the backend by GKE is the same as the SA used by the app, everything works fine. However, if we create a separate SA with the same permissions, but different from the one used by the app, issues arise. We are still investigating the exact cause.
